# How to use p-tiered menu in mat-sidenav content with router-outlet?

Tags: css, angular, submenu, mat-sidenav

we have used p-tiered menu to display submenus in mat-sidenav and we have placed  inside

p-tiered menu not displaying correctly in mat-sidenav as shown in below screenshot:

Here is the screenshot:

[image: screenshot alternate text]

It should display submenu (PQR, LMN) outside the context of mat-sidenav i.e. inside router outlet

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
  <mat-sidenav #projectnav
    mode="side"
   opened>
    <mat-nav-list>      
      <div *ngFor="let menuItem of menuArray" >
        {{ menuItem.visible }}                     
        <app-tiered-menu *ngIf="menuOpen" [menuItems]="[menuItem]">
        </app-tiered-menu>      
      </div>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
 <mat-card-content>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Comment: show your relevant code

Comment: i have updated the relevant code

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code where *I/we* can test?